# How to pass a variable through url and use it inside a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(String UserName)
    {
        using (var db = new MatchGamingEntities())
        {
            var Users = from m in db.Users
                        join m2 in db.MyProfiles on m.UserId equals m2.UserId
                        where m.UserName == UserName
                        select new UserViewModel
                        {
                            UserName = m.UserName,
                            LastActivityDate = m.LastActivityDate,
                            Address = m2.Address,
                            City = m2.City,
                            State = m2.State,
                            Zip = m2.Zip
                        };

            return View(Users.SingleOrDefault());
        }
    }
```

I type in the url Profiles/Details/hello, but it does not work, if I do Profiles/Details?UserName=hello then it works.  I have another ActionResult just like this except taking in an int id as parameter and it works fine with the first url format.

Comment: I think you need to set up the route so I knows how to deal with that url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to register a new route, something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "RouteName",
   "profiles/{action}/{userName}",
   new { controller = "Profiles", action = "Details", userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: +1 - In addition to this answer, @anthonypliu: The reason your integer value works is because the default MVC route uses this format {controller}/{action}/{id}. When you have an integer parameter on your action method called "Id", the route automatically attempts to bind the value to the parameter. If you want, look over how Value Providers work to get a more complete understanding.